# SlideDown working, SlideUp refusing to go back into hiding

Tags: jquery, drupal-7, ubercart

I have a problem hiding a attribute field based on a selection from another attribute field.

Since there is a lack of doing this easier, I thought of adding jQuery code in my footer block.

I will try to explain the current situation as good as possible.

I have a selection field that currently is being generated like this:

```
<select id="edit-attributes-4" class="form-select ajax-processed" name="attributes[4]">
<option selected="selected" value="12">
  Verzenden, €15.44
</option><option value="13">
  Ophalen, €8.03
</option></select>
```

And this:

```
<select id="edit-attributes-5" class="form-select ajax-processed" name="attributes[5]">
<option selected="selected" value="14">
  1 Fles, €15.44
</option><option value="15">
  1 Doos, €92.64
</option></select>
```

I want field edit-attribute-4 to be hidden on page load, so I added this in a CSS code which is also in the same footer block:

```
#edit-attributes-4 {
     display:none;
     clear: both;
}
```

The clear both was a suggestion from some google findings about the slideup not working, I am unsure as to what it does but it didn't make any difference anyways, at least the hiding does work on page load.

This bit is the jQuery code which is also in the footer block:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#edit-attributes-5").change(function(){

         if ($(#edit-attributes-5).val() == "15" ) {
             $("#edit-attributes-4").slideDown("fast")

         } else {
              $("#edit-attributes-4").slideUp("fast")
         }
     });
 });
```

Basically what happens, and what works perfectly fine, is whenever attribute field 5 is changed to value 15, which is to buy 1 dozen instead of 1 single product, it shows the attribute field 4 to be able to select value 13 which gives discount for picking it up instead of shipping it to the customer.

This all works like it should and whenever I select value 15 in field 5, field 4 pops up and I am able to select anything in it, however, when I select value 14 in field 5, field 4 does not go back into hiding.

Basically what I want to achieve with this is to have 2 cloned fields for sending or shipping, in which 1 has the discount in it for selecting the dozen instead of the single product. This to prevent people from ordering 1 single product while putting form 4 to value 13 and get the same discount on it as if they chose to come and get a dozen themselves at the store and not having it shipped to them, which is what the discount is all about. I hope this makes any sense.

Can anybody shed some light as to why this is not working like it should? Why is it not going back into hiding? Am I missing something here? I am not really into jQuery a lot so it might just be something really obvious. If there are easier alternatives then I'm open for suggestions.

Update:
http://jsfiddle.net/zhmSS/
fiddle seems to work like a charm..
However on my product page it keeps failing, even when

```
if ($(#edit-attributes-5).val() == "15" ) {
```

is changed to:

```
if ($(this).val() == "15" ) {
```

Something must be breaking it?
I have tried using jQuery update on Drupal and select jQuery v1.5, v1.7 and v1.8, but none of them make a difference.

The page in question:
http://italvin.arclyse.net/?q=producten&w=Rode%20Wijn&s=All&wh=All&d=All

Comment: Is this a typos `if ($(#edit-attributes-5)` because it should be `if ($('#edit-attributes-5')`. You can also replace it with `$(this).val()`.

Comment: It would also help if you post a jsFiddle demo.

Comment: Hi Omar,
I forgot to mention that i tried both, the way it looks now makes it slide down aswell, it used to be 'this' before aswell, but since it didnt work i tried alternative approaches. The funny thing is, when i try these codes in fiddle and i change if ($(#edit-attributes-5) into this it works like a charm, however, on the page it needs to work it doesnt.

Comment: @Shivam : http://jsfiddle.net/zhmSS/ Seems to work perfectly fine, it wont however on my product page: http://italvin.arclyse.net/?q=producten&w=Rode%20Wijn&s=All&wh=All&d=All

Comment: To be honest, it is very difficult to understand what you are trying to accomplish. Your question asks "SlideDown working, SlideUp refusing", Is your goal to make slideUp work? 

SlideUp wont work propely with select elements unless they are styled differently. Might I suggest using fadeIn() and fadeOut()?

jsFiddle update: http://jsfiddle.net/zhmSS/1/

Answer (score 0):

If this is in Drupal, you have to structure your jquery a bit differently. Drupal uses a behaviors system which ensures that your javascript code runs whenever content is added via ajax. Right now, your jquery function will never run, because the document is "ready" before your form is fully loaded.

Here is a reference for [working with javascript in Drupal](https://drupal.org/node/171213)

Here's a typical way of attaching behaviors in Drupal:

```
(function ($, Drupal, window, document, undefined) {

    Drupal.behaviors.selectionHandlers = {
        attach: function( context, settings ) {

             $("#edit-attributes-5").once("select-handler", function() {

                  $(this).change(function(){
                      if ($("#edit-attributes-5").val() == "15" ) {
                           $("#edit-attributes-4").slideDown("fast")
                      } else {
                           $("#edit-attributes-4").slideUp("fast")
                      }
                  });
             });
         }
     }

})(jQuery, Drupal, this, this.document);
```

Adding it as a behavior says "run this code when new content is added to the page".

The `once()` call ensures the code runs only when the content is initially added, and not when other content is added.

Comment: Thank you for explaining and providing the example, however, when i add this method to the page, i see 1 thing that makes it clear something was indeed going wrong, wich is that it now actually slides down like it should with a neat effect, but it will still not hide the selection list back when the value is back to 14. What i did now is replace my jquery code block with yours and leave the rest as it is, but still no go. Seeing as you seem to know more about drupal itself, do you know perhaps something is blocking the whole jquery?

Comment: I think what is happening is that when you change your `Afname` selection, the entire form is reloaded via ajax, meaning that `#edit-attributes-5` has been removed and replaced, which removes its `change()` event handler, so it will fire the first time, but not the second. To test if this is the case, add an `alert()` or `console.log()` call to the change handler, and see if it is being called. Generally, you wouldn't add the drupal behavior to the header of the view, you would put it in a `.js` file which your theme loads ( typically in your `theme.info` file ).